# Generic Methods in Java: "Object does not take parameters"

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to create a generic method inside a class which takes an array of given type objects and sorts them to return a pair object containing the minimum array item and the maximum array item.

At the moment I get 3 compiler errors:

- type Object does not take parameters: `public <FirstType> Pair sortMinMax(Object<FirstType>[] array)`
- type Object does not take parameters: `Object<FirstType> minimum = array[0]`
- type Object does not take parameters: `Object<FirstType> maximum = array[0]`

Here is my Class:

```
public class MinMaxArray {

  // takes an array of a given object and returns a pair 
  // of the min and max array elements
  public <FirstType> Pair sortMinMax(Object<FirstType>[] array) {
    Object<FirstType> minimum = array[0];
    Object<FirstType> maximum = array[0];

    // loop through all array items and perform sort
    for (int counter = 1; counter < array.length; counter++) {
      // if this element is less than current min, set as min
      // else if this element is greater than current max, set as max
      if (array[counter].compareTo(minimum) < 0) {
        minimum = array[counter];
      } else if (array[counter].comparTo(maximum) > 0) {
        maximum = array[counter];
      } // end if else new min, max
    } // end for (all array items)

    return new Pair<FirstType, FirstType>(minimum, maximum);
  } // end compare()

} // end MinMaxArray
```

Comment: `java.lang.Object` is not generic

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, avoid reference arrays. They don't play well with generics. Use `List` instead.

It's not clear to me if you intend `FirstType` to be a type or a generic parameter (which would usually be given a single letter name).

If `FirstType` is a type

```
public static Pair<FirstType,FirstType> sortMinMax(List<FirstType> things) {
```

If you mean a generic parameter, look at `java.util.Collections.sort`.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
```

So

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Pair<T,T> sortMinMax(List<T> list) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type Object does not take parameters
```

This is what tells you most. Simply, you can write things like `Object<T>`. The class `Object` is not parameterized. `List`s for example, are.

Also, in order to use the `compareTo()` method, you need to have something like this:

```
public <FirstType extends Comparable> Pair sortMinMax(FirstType[] array)
```

Comment: `Comparable` and `Pair` are generic so will need arguments. The array is going to make things tricky.

Comment: Definitely true.